# El término 'python' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable

Tags: python, django, terminal

Estoy utilizando la terminal en VS code para correr Django y de un día para el otro me dejo de funcionar, yo utilizaba los comandos `c:/Users/alumno/PycharmProjects/SELIU/venv/Scripts/activate.bat` y `python manage.py runserver` y el servidor ya corría normalmente, ahora al hacer eso ya no funciona,

```
python : El término 'python' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o 
programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió 
correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e 
inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ python manage.py runserver
+ ~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

aclaro que al probarlo en la terminal de comando funciona correctamente (la cosa es que hay al hacer un cambio tengo que reiniciar el servidor yo mismo cada ves y comprenderán que es un problema.
uso Python 3.8.6, Django 2.2.3, y tengo windows 8.1.
**aclaraciones:**

- ya comprobé de que tengo Python bien instalado, de hecho el comando `py` me funciona correctamente pero no me deja iniciar el servidor
- tampoco funciona si utilizo el `./` o `.\` en el comando
- Me dejo de andar al hacer otro proyecto (un sitio web simple sin Django), pero estaban en carpetas distintas así que no creo que tenga relación (pero lo remarco por si acaso tiene algo que ver)
- las preguntas relacionas a mi problema no tenían la solución al mío.
- no probé desinstalando e instalando Python debido a que me anda bien en la terminal.
- cuando utilizo la terminal en VS me dice que es "powershell" y creo que esto no estaba antes

Comment: Para iniciar un ambiente virtual no debes lanzar el `activate.bat` sino más bien `activate` que es un archivo diferente. Puedes volver a crear otro ambiente virtual e instalar las dependencias para comprobar si ese es el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta descargar ni cambiar nada, creas la terminal y escribes `cmd` y ahí ya te tendrá que aparecer algo así como

> Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.3.9600]
> (c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

si ese es el caso ya puedes usar el `venv/Scripts/activate.bat` y luego el `python manage.py runserver`